# Understanding powerpoint effect object kind (entry,emphasis, exit) in c#

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop, effect

In powerpoint 2010, i want to uderstand effect object kind. Not the effect type. Let me explain my need. in powerpoint graphical interface we can see slide's timeline object. Effect object in timeline can be in three kind ; entry, emphasis or exit. Also we see "star" symbol near the shape name's and this symbols shows us the effect kind; green star for entry, yellow for emphasis and red for exit kind.

I wonder how powerpoint understand the effect kind.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain your need in greater detail? Code samples to demonstrate what you mean by 'object kind' would be useful; what you have tried and how your question relates to c#. It is very difficult to understand what exactly you are asking for.

Comment: thank for yor comment @Jay. let me explain in detail; in my code i need to understand powerpoint effect object kind that the effect was an entry,emphasis or exit effect. In effect object model EffectType property gives us aplied animation such as appear,fly or what ever but the effect kind. ı hope i can explained in detail this time. ans sorry for my english.